# AJAX response variable undefined

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have made a AJAX request and trying to show the result as HTML.

My controller:

```
public function searchByRange(Request $request)
{
    $query = DB::table('visitors')         
        ->where('id','=',$request->id)
        ->where('visitors.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)                
        ->whereBetween('visitors.created_at', array($request->first_date, $request->second_date) );        
        $visitors = $query->get();    
        return view('analytics.analytics-range',['visitors' => $visitors]); 
    }
```

My AJAX part:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "{{url('searchByRange')}}",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: 
    { 
        first_date : first_date, 
        second_date : second_date,  
        id : id                     
    },
    success: function(html)
    {
        $(".date-range").html(html)
    }
});
```

But the problem is ajax response in console is

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: visitors

What could be possible error for that?

Comment: Every time your visitors undefined or sometimes ? I mean every first_date and second_date.

Comment: everytime,  every first_date and second_date

Comment: Can show your analytics.analytics-range.blade.php?

Comment: Let's say right now i want to show only {{$visitors->count()}}

Answer (score 0):

try changing your controller function to:

```
public function searchByRange(Request $request)
{
    $visitors = DB::table('visitors')           
       ->where('id','=',$request->id)
       ->where('visitors.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)               
       ->whereBetween('visitors.created_at', array($request->first_date, $request->second_date))
       ->get();        

    return view('analytics.analytics-range',['visitors' => $visitors]); 
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why ajax doesn't support the code i have used before? 
Because in normal HTML the code works like a charm. And there is valid reason i have used above code and i can't disclose the full code here. Before finding visitors i have other line of statements which i didn't post.

Comment: Why is this an answer? What have you changed from OPs code? [Code-only answers are considered low-quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers) - explain what you've done, and why you think this helps.